# OSCommerce price schedule inconsistent behaviour

Tags: php, oop, oscommerce

Working on a problem with an "old" shop in OSCommerce. It's a multistore configuration which is tweaked by the previous owner. I have 2 similar products with a price schedule or quantity price break feature.

The problem is 1 of the 2 products is not reacting consistent when added to cart or showing the product page.

[1st product](http://www.siergrindwinkel.nl/splitplaat/stabilo-splitplaat-wit-30mm-p-1098.html): has a price schedule of >5, >10, >20 and >30, with prices from high to low.
[2nd product](http://www.siergrindwinkel.nl/splitplaat/stabilo-splitplaat-zwart-30mm-p-2722.html): has the same schedule but is somehow shown the other way around: >30, >20, >10 and >5 with prices from low to high.

The weird thing is that the option sort_order does not exist in the price schedule table so the way that the quantity order is shown is random, but always from high to low or low to high.

The first product shows the correct price in the shopping cart, the second product always shows the highest price at any quantity, where the shopping cart should adjust the price according to the price schedule data.

Done so far without any luck:

- Checked the price schedule configuration in backend
- Checked product configuration in backend and rechecked in Database
- Checked all related database tables
- After discovering that the only difference between the products are: product name, product image and product_id, gave the product an product_id close to the working one. Also changed all the related database entry's
- Make a copy of the correctly working product and add a price schedule as well.

Here is the code of the class which generates the price_schedule:

```
<?php
/*
  $Id: price_schedule.php,v 1.0 2004/08/23 22:50:52 rmh Exp $

  osCommerce, Open Source E-Commerce Solutions
  http://www.oscommerce.com

  Copyright (c) 2003 osCommerce

  Released under the GNU General Public License
*/

/*
    price_schedule.php - module to support customer classes with quantity pricing
    Originally Created 2003, Beezle Software based on some code mods by WasaLab Oy (Thanks!)
    Modified by Ryan Hobbs (hobbzilla)
*/

class PriceFormatter {
  var $hiPrice;
  var $lowPrice;
  var $quantity;
  var $hasQuantityPrice;
  var $hasSpecialPrice;
  var $qtyPriceBreaks;

  function PriceFormatter($prices=NULL) {
    $this->productsID = -1;

    $this->hasQuantityPrice=false;
    $this->hasSpecialPrice=false;

    $this->hiPrice=-1;
    $this->lowPrice=-1;
    $this->thePrice = -1;
    $this->specialPrice = -1;
    $this->qtyBlocks = 1;
    $this->qtyPriceBreaks = 0;

    if($prices) {
      $this->parse($prices);
    }
  }

  function encode() {
    $str = $this->productsID . ":"
           . (($this->hasQuantityPrice == true) ? "1" : "0") . ":"
           . (($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) ? "1" : "0") . ":"
           . $this->quantity[1] . ":"
           . $this->quantity[2] . ":"
           . $this->quantity[3] . ":"
           . $this->quantity[4] . ":"
           . $this->price[1] . ":"
           . $this->price[2] . ":"
           . $this->price[3] . ":"
           . $this->price[4] . ":"
           . $this->thePrice . ":"
           . $this->specialPrice . ":"
           . $this->qtyBlocks . ":"
           . $this->taxClass;
    return $str;
  }

  function decode($str) {
    list($this->productsID,
         $this->hasQuantityPrice,
         $this->hasSpecialPrice,
         $this->quantity[1],
         $this->quantity[2],
         $this->quantity[3],
         $this->quantity[4],
         $this->price[1],
         $this->price[2],
         $this->price[3],
         $this->price[4],
         $this->thePrice,
         $this->specialPrice,
         $this->qtyBlocks,
         $this->taxClass) = explode(":", $str);

    $this->hasQuantityPrice = (($this->hasQuantityPrice == 1) ? true : false);
    $this->hasSpecialPrice = (($this->hasSpecialPrice == 1) ? true : false);
  }

  function parse($prices) {
    global $customer_group_id, $customer_group_type, $customer_group_discount;
    if (!tep_not_null($customer_group_id)) {
      $customer_group_id = VISITOR_PRICING_GROUP;
      $check_group_query = tep_db_query("select customers_groups_type, customers_groups_discount from " . TABLE_CUSTOMERS_GROUPS . " where customers_groups_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "'");
      $check_group = tep_db_fetch_array($check_group_query);
      $customer_group_type = $check_group['customers_groups_type'];
      $customer_group_discount = $check_group['customers_groups_discount'];
    }
    $this->productsID = $prices['products_id'];
    $this->hasQuantityPrice=false;
    $this->hasSpecialPrice=false;

//    if ($customer_group_type != '1') {
//         $price_schedule_query = tep_db_query("select products_groups_price, products_groups_price_qty FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_PRICE_SCHEDULES . " WHERE products_id = '" . $prices['products_id'] . "' and customers_groups_id = '" . (int)$customer_group_id . "' and stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "'");
         $price_schedule_query = tep_db_query("select products_groups_price, products_groups_price_qty FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_PRICE_SCHEDULES . " WHERE products_id = '" . $prices['products_id'] . "' and stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "'");

         $this->qtyPriceBreaks = tep_db_num_rows($price_schedule_query);
         $this->thePrice = $prices['products_price'];
         $this->specialPrice = $prices['specials_new_products_price'];
//    } else {
//         $this->qtyPriceBreaks = 0;
//         $this->thePrice = $prices['products_price'] * (100 - $customer_group_discount)/100;
//         $this->specialPrice = $prices['specials_new_products_price'];
//         if ($this->thePrice < $this->specialPrice) $this->specialPrice = "";
//    }

    $this->hiPrice = $this->thePrice;
    $this->lowPrice = $this->thePrice;
    $this->hasSpecialPrice = tep_not_null($this->specialPrice);

    $this->qtyBlocks = $prices['products_qty_blocks'];
    $this->taxClass=$prices['products_tax_class_id'];
    $n = 0;

    if ($this->qtyPriceBreaks > 0 ) {
      while ($price_schedule = tep_db_fetch_array($price_schedule_query)) {
        $this->price[$n]=$price_schedule['products_groups_price'];
        $this->quantity[$n]=$price_schedule['products_groups_price_qty'];
        if ($this->quantity[$n] == '1') {
          $this->thePrice = $this->price[$n];
          $this->hiPrice = $this->thePrice;
          $this->lowPrice = $this->thePrice;
        } else {
          $this->hasQuantityPrice = true;
        }
        $n += 1;
      }
    }

    for($i=0; $i<$this->qtyPriceBreaks; $i++) {
      if ($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) {
        $this->hiPrice = $this->specialPrice;
        if ($this->price[$i] > $this->specialPrice) {
          $this->price[$i] = $this->specialPrice;
        }
      }

      if ($this->hasQuantityPrice == true) {
        if ($this->price[$i] > $this->hiPrice) {
          $this->hiPrice = $this->price[$i];
        }
        if ($this->price[$i] < $this->lowPrice) {
          $this->lowPrice = $this->price[$i];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  function loadProduct($product_id, $language_id=1)
  {
    $sql="select pd.products_name, p.products_model, p.products_image, p.products_leadtime, p.products_id, p.manufacturers_id, p.products_price, p.products_weight, p.products_unit, p.products_qty_blocks, p.products_tax_class_id, p.distributors_id, IF(s.status = '1' AND s.stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "', s.specials_new_products_price, NULL) as specials_new_products_price, IF(s.status = '1' AND s.stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "', s.specials_new_products_price, p.products_price) as final_price from " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_CATEGORIES . " p2c, ((" . TABLE_PRODUCTS . " p left join " . TABLE_MANUFACTURERS . " m on p.manufacturers_id = m.manufacturers_id, " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . " pd) left join " . TABLE_SPECIALS . " s on p.products_id = s.products_id and s.stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "') INNER JOIN " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_TO_STORES . " p2s ON p.products_id = p2s.products_id where p2s.stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "' AND p.products_status = '1' and p.products_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' and pd.products_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "' and pd.language_id = '". (int)$language_id ."'";

    $product_info_query = tep_db_query($sql);
    $product_info = tep_db_fetch_array($product_info_query);
    $this->parse($product_info);

    return $product_info;
  }

  function computePrice($qty)  {

    $qty = $this->adjustQty($qty);
    $price = $this->thePrice;


    if ($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) {
        $price = $this->specialPrice;
    }

    if ($this->hasQuantityPrice == true) {
      for ($i=0; $i<$this->qtyPriceBreaks; $i++) {

        if (($this->quantity[$i] > 0) && ($qty >= $this->quantity[$i])) {
          $price = $this->price[$i];
        }
      }
    }
    return $price;
  }

// Force QTY_BLOCKS granularity
  function adjustQty($qty) {

    $qb = $this->getQtyBlocks();
    if ($qty < 1) {
      $qty = 0;
      return $qty;
    }

    if ($qb >= 1) {
      if ($qty < $qb) {
        $qty = $qb;
      }

      if (($qty % $qb) != 0) {
        $qty += ($qb - ($qty % $qb));
      }
    }
    return $qty;
  }

  function getQtyBlocks() {
    return $this->qtyBlocks;
  }

  function getPrice() {
    return $this->thePrice;
  }

  function getLowPrice() {
    return $this->lowPrice;
  }

  function getHiPrice() {
    return $this->hiPrice;
  }

  function hasSpecialPrice() {
    return $this->hasSpecialPrice;
  }

  function hasQuantityPrice() {
    return $this->hasQuantityPrice;
  }

  function getPriceString($style='productPriceInBox') {
    global $currencies, $customer_id;

// If you want to change the format of the price/quantity table
// displayed on the product information page, here is where you do it.

    if (($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) && ($this->hasQuantityPrice == false)) {
      $lc_text = '&nbsp;<s>' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</s>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="productSpecialPrice">' . $currencies->display_price($this->specialPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</span>';
    }

    if($this->hasQuantityPrice == true) {
      $lc_text = '<table align="top" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="center" colspan="2"><b>' . ($this->hasSpecialPrice == true ? '<s>' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</s>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="productSpecialPrice">' . $currencies->display_price($this->specialPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</span>&nbsp;' : 'vanaf&nbsp;' . $currencies->display_price($this->lowPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) ) . '</b></td></tr>';

      for($i=0; $i<=$this->qtyPriceBreaks; $i++) {
        if(($this->quantity[$i] > 0) && ($this->price[$i] > $this->specialPrice)) {
          $lc_text .= '<tr><td class='.$style.' align="right">>&nbsp;' . $this->quantity[$i] . '&nbsp;</td><td class='.$style.'>' . $currencies->display_price($this->price[$i], tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</td></tr>';
        }
      }
      $lc_text .= '</table>';
    } else {
      if ($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) {
        $lc_text = '&nbsp;<s>' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</s>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="productSpecialPrice">' . $currencies->display_price($this->specialPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</span>';
      } else {
        $lc_text = '&nbsp;' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '';
      }
    }
//    if (VISITOR_PRICING_GROUP < '0' && !tep_session_is_registered('customer_id')) {
//      return '';
//    } else {
      return $lc_text;
//    }
  }

  function getPriceStringShort() {
    global $currencies, $customer_id;

    if (($this->hasSpecialPrice == true) && ($this->hasQuantityPrice == false)) {
      $lc_text = '<div class="priceold">' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</div><div class="pricenew">' . $currencies->display_price($this->specialPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</div>';
    } elseif ($this->hasQuantityPrice == true) {
      $lc_text = '<div class="vanaf">vanaf</div><div class="price">' . $currencies->display_price($this->lowPrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '&nbsp;</div>';
    } else {
      $lc_text = '<div class="price">' . $currencies->display_price($this->thePrice, tep_get_tax_rate($this->taxClass)) . '</div>';
    }

//    if (VISITOR_PRICING_GROUP < '0' && !tep_session_is_registered('customer_id')) {
//      return TEXT_LOGIN_TO_SEE_PRICES;
//    } else {
      return $lc_text;
//    }
  }
}
?>
```

I'm not experienced enough to decipher the class and find strange things, if you need more info, do not hesitate to ask.
Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you would like the product prices to be ordered consistently.  I'm aware of the addons you mention but I'm not very familiar with them. That being said you can try to change this line...

```
$price_schedule_query = tep_db_query("select products_groups_price, products_groups_price_qty FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_PRICE_SCHEDULES . " WHERE products_id = '" . $prices['products_id'] . "' and stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "'");
```

to

```
$price_schedule_query = tep_db_query("select products_groups_price, products_groups_price_qty FROM " . TABLE_PRODUCTS_PRICE_SCHEDULES . " WHERE products_id = '" . $prices['products_id'] . "' and stores_id = '" . STORES_ID . "'" . " ORDER BY products_groups_price ASC");
```

As I said, I'm not familiar with exactly how the addons you mentioned work but I'd start by adding ordering to the mysql query.  This approach has worked for me on numerous occasions with various addons.

Comment: Thank you very much ndiggity, that worked like a charm, i only had to change ASC to DESC.